# Trying to run a PFQuery that will lead to only one result being returned however the parameters that I am envoking are not specific enough

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I am trying to run a PFQuery in order to find specific results for an address stored in the server. However, when I try for a specific address I am always returned 0. The fields that this class possesses are objectId, startTime and title. I am unsure if this is the best way to pose the question but is there a type of general format that would allow me to query for the latest address stored and return that as a string in the code? Here is what I have written thus far in my load screen view controller, which is designed to place a user based on her/his location.

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Parse

class LoadViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var lastUserLocation = "nil"

  var address = ""
var startTime = ""

func findEventProximity(eventObjectId: String){

    var eventObjectIdQuery = PFQuery(className: "Events")
    eventObjectIdQuery.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    eventObjectIdQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: eventObjectId)
    eventObjectIdQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil  {
            print(objects!.count)
            if let objects = objects as [PFObject]? {
                for object in objects {
                    object["objectId"] = selectedEventObjectId

                    /*   need to decide wether to store Time  in createNewEvent  as NSDate or just string
                     if object["date"] != nil {
                     self.eventDateLabel.text = object["date"] as! NSDate
                     }
                     */

                  print("\(object["address"] as! String)")
                }
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }






    })

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    findEventProximity(selectedEventObjectId)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

/*MARK: LOCATION*/
/*MARK: LOCATION*/
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]

    let userLocationLat = locations[0].coordinate.latitude
    let userLocationLong = locations[0].coordinate.longitude
    var location = CLLocation(latitude: userLocationLat, longitude: userLocationLong)


    print("\(userLocationLat), \(userLocationLong)")





    let locationsToCheck: [CLLocation] = [
        CLLocation(latitude: lat, long),
        CLLocation(latitude: lat, long),
        CLLocation(latitude: lat, long),
        CLLocation(latitude: lat, long)
    ]
    let locationTags: [String] = [
        "P1",
        "P2",
        "P3",
        "P4"
    ]
    var closestInMeters: Double = 50000.0
    var closestIndex: Int = -1

    for (locationIndex, potentialLocation) in locationsToCheck.enumerate() {
        let proximityToLocationInMeters: Double = userLocation.distanceFromLocation(potentialLocation)

        if proximityToLocationInMeters < closestInMeters {
            closestInMeters = proximityToLocationInMeters
            closestIndex = locationIndex

        }
    }

    if (closestIndex == -1) {
        self.lastUserLocation = "Other"

        //            SCLAlertView().showError("No Filter Range", subTitle: "Sorry! We haven’t got a Filter Range for you yet, email us and we’ll get right on it.").setDismissBlock({ () -> Void in
        //                selectedLocation = self.locationObjectIdArray[0]
        //                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("eventTableSegue", sender: self)
        //            })
        //                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        //            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    } else if locationTags[closestIndex] != self.lastUserLocation {
        self.lastUserLocation = locationTags[closestIndex]

    }


}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Comment: if you know the objectID you should use function getObjectInBackground() and not findObjectsInBackground....

Comment: so then by adding the parameter wherekey.orderByDescending would that only return one data point from the search bc ultimately it needs to be dynamic in the sense that it will always grab the latest address posted and not just the one specified by the query specifically

Comment: objectID is unique you cant have more than one in your DB class with same objectID!!!!! or you are using pointers that might have same IDs? if yes you would have to build your query differently

Comment: yes i think i may need to structure it differently. Essentially based on the nature of the app a user creates an event and another user needs to be checked in in the background to that event based on location and proximity. So what I am seeking to do is get the creator of the event (User 1)'s coordinates, store that as a string value in parse then the attendee (User 2) encounters a load screen that gathers their location and queris the other class to see if the event coordinates match up. However im not sure how such a query would work?